# ListBox - I need to remove an item, but it keeps duplicating them

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm using C#. And my question is about a nasty ListBox that just doesn't want to listen.

Code:

```
        void client_UserAvailable(object sender, IMAvailEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            if (listBoxContacts.Items != null)
            {
                string available = "";
                if (e.IsAvailable)
                    available = "Online";
                else
                    available = "Offline";

                if (listBoxContacts.Items.Count <= 0 || !listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName))
                    listBoxContacts.Items.Add(e.UserName + " " + available);
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listBoxContacts.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string _user = (string)listBoxContacts.Items[i];
                        _user.Replace(_user, e.UserName + " " + available);
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

Once I run that event, it will add the user(s) name to the list if the ListBox's item count is less than or equal to 0 or if the ListBox.Items doesn't contain the username. If it contains the username or if the count is greater, it will then update the user(s) status in the for loop.

HOWEVER, when trying to replace the value, it just duplicates it. I also tried adding a 'Remove(_user)' below '_user.Replace(_user, e.UserName + " " + available);', but it just duplicates.

I can fix this issue by adding a 'ListBox.Items.Clear' inside of my timer that updates the ListBox at a 5 second interval:

```
        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isOnline)
        {
            if (listBoxContacts.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (string user in friends)
                {
                    listBoxContacts.Items.Clear();
                    client.IsAvailable(user);
                    if (infoWindow != null)
                    {
                        infoWindow.Close();
                        infoWindow = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

BUT, the ListBox items blink. I don't want it to blink, so I'm trying to find alternatives. I searched throughout a lot of related questions, but none were successfully helpful. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the underlying type of the the listbox items - string, or some other type? And what values can an item for an existing user take - just the username, or `username + " " + available`?

Comment: Types are only a string. And yes, it is just the username space availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments it looks like the first problem is this clause:

```
!listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName)
```

If the existing item is always username + (space) + availability, then that clause will always return false, and therefore always trigger the addition of a new entry.
You should change that clause to something like:

```
(!listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName + " Online" ) && !listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName + " Offline"))
```

The next problem is the loop - looks like you end up trying to update the status for everyone in the list, not just the particular user that the event relates to.

And finally you're not replacing the existing value in the listbox.

You probably need to do something like:

```
string currentItem = listBoxContacts.Items[i];
if(currentItem.Contains(e.UserName))
{
    listBoxContacts.Items[i] = e.UserName + " " + available;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I can't believe I didn't catch the first problem (The 'Contains(e.UserName);') -- Okay. So, I tried your method and it is somehow just duplicating the first user on my friends list (ListBox).

Comment: Had a bit more of a think, and might have found a couple of other issues - see latest edit, let me know how that goes

Comment: It works great; however, when one of my friends go offline, it will duplicate his name & status.

Comment: does the updated if statement look like this now: `if(listBoxContacts.Items.Count <= 0 || (!listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName + " Online") && !listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName + " Offline")))`? If they were online and then go offline, then there should be an existing entry in the listbox with 'online', so it should get caught by the `!listBoxContacts.Items.Contains(e.UserName + " Online")` clause, and therefore drop into the replacement code instead of the 'add new' code

Comment: I did that, but I apparently removed a line that was causing the issue. I tested with a few of my BETA testers and it works! Thanks for taking your time to figure this out with me.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your use of [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the method returns a string it does not alter the original string.

From above link:

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode character or String in the current string are replaced with another specified Unicode character or String.

So I would do something like:

```
listBoxContacts.Items[i] = _user.Replace(_user, e.UserName + " " + available);
```

---

You are going to have to check for the UserName in your `for` statement or else you will get the username  repeating in your list

something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxContacts.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (((string)listBoxContacts.Items[i]).Contains(e.UserName))
    {
        listBoxContacts.Items[i] =  e.UserName + " " + available;
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: It does the same thing as chamila_c's method. Here is my comment towards that: "It works great; however, when one of my friends go offline, it will duplicate his name & status."

Comment: @user1322822 The change that I made will break out of the loop after the first match. It did not duplicate in my tests.

Comment: @user1322822 Please add your current modified code to your question then.

Answer (score 1):

The replace method doesn't change _user as strings are immutable, instead you should use

```
_user = _user.Replace(_user, e.UserName + " " + available);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but it will still duplicate however.